# Program to change letters into numbers similar to a phone keypad

Tags: python-3.x

This program lets the user enter a phone number to which it will then output the numbers for it. For example, they enter letters such as, 1-800-flowers it will then output 1-800-3569377.

Current Problem I am having with this: Whenever I enter a phone number I do not receive an output of any kind.

Ideas?

```
 #This program will be used to convert a telephone number with letters in it to numbers.

 def getNumber(uppercaseLetter):
     if uppercaseLetter == 'A' or uppercaseLetter == 'a' or uppercaseLetter == 'B' or uppercaseLetter == 'b' or uppercaseLetter == 'C' or uppercaseLetter == 'c':
         return(2)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'D' or uppercaseLetter == 'd' or uppercaseLetter == 'E' or uppercaseLetter == 'e' or uppercaseLetter == 'F' or uppercaseLetter == 'f':
         return(3)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'G' or uppercaseLetter == 'g' or uppercaseLetter == 'H' or uppercaseLetter == 'h' or uppercaseLetter == 'I' or uppercaseLetter == 'i':
         return(4)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'J' or uppercaseLetter == 'j' or uppercaseLetter == 'K' or uppercaseLetter == 'k' or uppercaseLetter == 'L' or uppercaseLetter == 'l':
         return(5)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'M' or uppercaseLetter == 'm' or uppercaseLetter == 'N' or uppercaseLetter == 'n' or uppercaseLetter == 'O' or uppercaseLetter == 'o':
         return(6)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'P' or uppercaseLetter == 'p' or uppercaseLetter == 'Q' or uppercaseLetter == 'q' or uppercaseLetter == 'R' or uppercaseLetter == 'r' or uppercaseLetter == 'S' or uppercaseLetter == 's':
         return(7)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'T' or uppercaseLetter == 't' or uppercaseLetter == 'U' or uppercaseLetter == 'u' or uppercaseLetter == 'V' or uppercaseLetter == 'v':
         return(8)
     elif uppercaseLetter == 'W' or uppercaseLetter == 'w' or uppercaseLetter == 'X' or uppercaseLetter == 'x' or uppercaseLetter == 'Y' or uppercaseLetter == 'y' or uppercaseLetter == 'Z' or uppercaseLetter == 'z':
         return(9)


 def numberTranslate():
     phoneNumber = str(input("Please enter a phone number to be converted: "))
     for ch in phoneNumber:
         if ch in    ['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z']:
            result = getNumber(ch)
            return result

         else:
             return ch

     print(phoneNumber)
numberTranslate()
```

Comment: Tabs are meaningful in Python.  My first guess, looking at how your code is formatted, is that you've got a whitespace problem.

Comment: Sorry I realize now that I missed a few indentations when transferring the code over. Let me change them now.

Comment: Don't do it for my sake.  I won't be reviewing all your code to see where you went wrong.  Think about how you could manage this by writing less code.  (Hint: Think about a dictionary instead of a wall of if/else.)

Comment: I will have to look into that in the future thanks!